# BCLK large drops (90 MHz): Should I be worried ? (No OC or other modifications)

Tags: windows, cpu

After some weird behaviours of Win10 *(a severe clock drift of several minutes per actual hour)*, I started monitoring **BCLK**, using different tools (Intel XTU, OCCT...).

They all reported the same: BCLK is overall stable at 100 Mhz (oscillating between 100.1 and 100.3); and then there are **sudden drops to ~90 Mhz**, which is far more than an "acceptable" 2-3% deviation.

XTU screenshot showing delta:

[image: XTU screenshot showing delta]

Additional info: All settings standard in the BIOS, no overclocking. Tried with and without CPU Spread Spectrum, with no difference.

Any ideas what could cause this: PSU/Voltage issue? Ageing components (PC is >5y old)? Temperature variations?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the age of your components nor does it have anything to do with PSU/Voltage issues.  I would only expect that behavior with internal adjustments to overcome temperature issues. When the reference clock frequency decreases the processor frequency also drop, which is perfectly normal, for a processor adjusting it's operating temperature automatically during a high temperature event.  Your graph does not display the temperature at that time.

Comment: If the clock time starts to drift appreciably, check the **clock** coin cell. Some cells last ten or more years, but 5 years (plus time from cell manufacture to sale of PC) is not unreasonable. Since ylou don't state the PC model, we can't provide help changing that cell.